Programmatic access to Github Copilot in VSCode primary sidebar
I am trying to automate the process of interacting with Github Copilot chat in Visual Studio Code. The chat view occurs in what VS Code usually calls "Primary Sidebar".
Is there a way to get programmatic access to the responses generated by Copilot here?
I looked at VS Code's integrated Dev Tools and located the HTML which contains the generated response, but this doesn't seem very useful.
<div class="monaco-list-row" role="listitem" data-index="4" data-last-element="false" data-parity="even" aria-setsize="7" aria-posinset="4" id="list_id_10_4" aria-selected="false" aria-label="1 file tree 1 code block:


huh. pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't dig it up again. maybe it got roomba-ed.
